# How to use Apache mod_rewrite RewriteCond to redirect a link?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am having some difficulty redirecting links. Here is a simple example and I hope you can tell me what I am missing that is causing it to fail.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} NAV=PIXIES
RewriteRule ^/category.asp?NAV=PIXIES /category/pop-artpixies-trade- [R=301,L,NE]
```

Please let me know what further information I can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the query string isn't included in the URI for matching in the `RewriteRule` directive:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} NAV=PIXIES
RewriteRule ^/category.asp$ /category/pop-artpixies-trade- [R=301,L,NE]
```

If this is inside an .htaccess file, you need to remove the leading slash in your regexp match:

```
RewriteRule ^category.asp$ /category/pop-artpixies-trade- [R=301,L,NE]
```

If you want to actually **remove** the `NAV=PIXIES` from the query string (because the above rule will rewrite http://domain/category.asp?NAV=PIXIES to http://domain/category/pop-artpixies-trade-?NAV=PIXIES ) then you need to add a "?" to the end of your target:

```
RewriteRule ^category.asp$ /category/pop-artpixies-trade-? [R=301,L,NE]
```